# BIDS and SSIS projects on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have trouble just getting started with BIDS, the development environment for creating SSIS packages in SQL Server 2005. I don't know if it is just a license / version issue or if i am missing some components.

If i install SQL Server Express 2005, there is NO BIDS component.

If i install SQL Server Express 2005 Toolkit, there IS BIDS component; but when i try to create a new project, there is NO "SSIS package" project template.

I try to install it on different machines, with same results.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2005 Express (and Workgroup) Edition BI Development Studio only includes the Report Designer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the installer installs 'workstation components' - sometimes it doesn't install these by default.  Known annoyance with the SQL Server 2005 installer and I've seen this asked on SO before so you're not the only one who's bumped into this.

Comment: I assume "workstation components" are not the same as "client components", are they? Because i do install each client component:
connectivity, bids, software dev kit, management studio. I am able to start BIDS, but SSIS project templates are missing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i am answering myself. I put my hands on a "Standard edition" SQL Server 2005 CD, installed "client components" as i did before, et voilà, the SSIS projects are now available.

My conclusion: you cannot create SSIS packages with SQL Server 2005 Express Edition.